# How to set end time of one job to start time of next job using python logic?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have to implement one logic in which End time of one job will become the start time of next job and print them.
I don't want to do this scheduling.
The data is coming as dataframe

```
Start Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
End Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

how can be use start time and end time in loop so that dataframe print like this.
example:

```
Master Job   Start Time   End Time
IM_BRIDGE    03:27:15     03:27:21
RECORDTYPE   03:27:21     03:27:35
ACCOUNT      03:27:35     03:27:55
MEDAFF       03:27:55     03:28:05
```

Can you please help me how to implement logic in python?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Can you please give example of data you are getting in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my limited understanding of your question here is try at giving answer,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time

data = [('IM_BRIDGE', '', ''), ('RECORDTYPE', '', ''), ('ACCOUNT', '', ''), ('MEDAFF', '', '')]

dtframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Master Job', 'Start Time', 'End Time'])

for index, item in enumerate(dtframe.get_values()):
    if index == 0:
        dtframe.xs(0)['Start Time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        time.sleep(2)
        dtframe.xs(0)['End Time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue

    if dtframe.xs(index-1)['End Time']:
        dtframe.xs(index)['Start Time'] = dtframe.xs(index-1)['End Time']
        dtframe.xs(index)['End Time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(2)

print dtframe
```

At few places using `time.sleep` in between to distinguish start and end time.

**Output:**

```
   Master Job Start Time  End Time
0   IM_BRIDGE   15:05:17  15:05:19
1  RECORDTYPE   15:05:19  15:05:21
2     ACCOUNT   15:05:21  15:05:23
3      MEDAFF   15:05:23  15:05:25
```